# Che cosa significa "rimandare a nuovo ruolo"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il contesto*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> "Ma ne avete parlato?" 
>         "Sì, ma soltanto da un punto di vista diciamo tecnico: se, venuto meno l'accusatore, il processo sarebbe ricominciato da capo o se la legge prevedeva una sostituzione." 
>         "E Cres sperava in una sostituzione  e che il processo non **venisse rimandato a nuovo ruolo**."

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "rimandare a nuovo ruolo"? Ho cercato alla voce "ruolo" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nel linguaggio giuridico, [mettere a ruolo](https://www.giustizia.it/giustizia/it/mg_3_7_9.page) una causa significa iscriverla nel registro dei processi pendenti davanti a quel determinato giudice.

> Occorre, a tal fine, che la parte che si costituisce in giudizio per
>   prima, di regola l’attore, depositi nella cancelleria, unitamente al
>   proprio fascicolo, la nota di iscrizione a ruolo, cioè un’istanza,
>   rivolta al cancelliere, di iscrivere la causa nel ruolo generale, ai
>   sensi dell’articolo 168 del codice di procedura civile.
>
> Il ruolo generale è il registro di tutti i processi pendenti davanti a
>   quel determinato giudice. La nota di iscrizione a ruolo deve contenere
>   l'indicazione:    
> •   delle parti, loro generalità e codice fiscale   
> •   del
>   procuratore che si costituisce e relativo codice fiscale
>     
> •   dell'oggetto della domanda  
> •   della data di notificazione della
>   citazione     
> •   della data fissata per la prima udienza di comparizione
>   delle parti Il decreto 19 marzo 2015 con riferimento al processo
>   esecutivo per espropriazione presvisto dall'art. 159-bis disp. Att.
>   c.p.c. indica i dati da inserire nella nota

Nel contesto da te citato si auspica che la sostituzione del giudice consenta la prosecuzione del processo e non una nuova iscrizione a ruolo, che comporterebbe l’annullamento del procedimento in corso e la  partenza da zero di un altro processo.

Comment: Mettere il processo a nuovo ruolo significa quindi in pratica che sarebbe ricominciato da capo, se ho capito.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Esattamente. Il ruolo è il registro che riporta l’elenco dei processi a carico di un determinato giudice